# rewrite rule isn't triggered for urls with asp extension

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, asp-classic

We have an old site in classic asp. And we had a rewrite rule in webconfig to avoid 404 error for not existing pages. Previously it worked. Here is the rule

```
<rule name="articoliarchiviati" stopProcessing="true"> 
<match url="^articoli/archiviati/([0-9]+)-.+$" /> 
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
<add input="{REQUESTFILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
<add input="{REQUESTFILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
</conditions> 
<action type="Rewrite" url="/articoli/archiviati/ArticleRendering.asp?id={R:1}" /> 
</rule>
```

I see that rule itself works - e.g. when I access part of url -
/articoli/archiviati/32848-violenza-
I see that it went to ArticleRendering page

But when I access full url with .asp extension - it goes to 404 error in IIS instead of triggering rewrite rule. But previously it worked, maybe some IIS updates/changes? Also site works with Cloudlfare.

May you help to resolve this?

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see details about 404 error, and your parameters don't seem to match .asp extension.

Comment: It is kind of weird because usually people use the URL rewrite to remove the asp extension as by default it would required to use the exact full name of the page (ie with extension) and only with the URL Re-rewrite can you remove the extension ..